# Am i doing the Servlet-Filter correctly?

Tags: jsp, servlets, servlet-filters

Good day!

I am trying to disable access on pages that are not part of successful login. I stored the login username in a session so that i could determine if the session is null or not.

I have several pages so I've decided to create a filter in xml and filter servlet so I don't need to put the `if(session == null)` code on all the pages.

My code in servlet is as follows:

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // place your code here
            HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest)request;
            HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse)response;

            HttpSession session = req.getSession(false);
            RequestDispatcher rd;

            //need to get the servlet path
            String url = req.getServletPath();
            if( url.equals("/LoginServlet") || url.equals("/LogoutServlet") || url.equals("/login.html") ){
                chain.doFilter(request, response);
            } else {
                if(session == null){
                    rd = req.getRequestDispatcher("index.html");
                    rd.forward(req, res);
                } else {
                    chain.doFilter(request,response);
                }
            }
    }
```

and my xml filter is as follows:

```
<filter>
    <display-name>sessionFilter</display-name>
    <filter-name>sessionFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.test.demoSession.filter.sessionFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>sessionFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
</filter>
```

The problem is...

> 1. I still can access other servlets without going to the log-in screen.
>      What is the problem with my code.
> 2. How can i do this better?

Comment: Where are you actually dispatching login-screen, I am not finding such code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're only checking if the session has been created, not if the user has been logged in. This is wrong. The session *can* already be created long before the user logs in.

When you login an user, you should set it as a session attribute

```
request.getSession().setAttribute("user", user);
```

In the filter you should check on that instead

```
User user = (User) request.getSession().getAttribute("user");

if (user == null) {
    // Not logged in.
} else {
    // Logged in.
}
```

#### See also:

- [Our Servlet-Filters wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlet-filters/info)

Comment: Hi Mr Balusc!  Thank you again...  :)